# Exiting a program with user input from Functions in C++

Tags: c++

I am currently writing a version of the game "Mastermind" and would like it to exit any time the user enters the letter 'Q', whether it be from the main menu or during the game when asked to make a guess.

The issue I am having is that the selected user input is evaluated from within a function, often called from within another function and I am unsure of how to properly exit the game without neglecting cleanup of the current stack.

I assume I could try to make a custom exception (although I am unsure exactly how to do this in C++, still learning) and then place each call in main() that may call the menuSelection() function later within a try catch, however I dont know if this is optimal.

I will try to give a quick VERY summarized example of my program. Obviously leaving a lot of it out, just to show where my program is when it hits an exit scenario.

```
void printMainMenu(){
    cout<<"blah blah blah... Enter a selection: ";
    string input;
    getline(cin, input);
    menuSelection(input);
}

void menuSelection(string input){
    if(input == 'Q')
        Exit Program; // <-- Need to exit when here
    else
        (other options);
}


int main(){
    printMainMenu(); // <-- menuSelection called here

    while(cin >> solution){
        GameBoard currentGame = GameBoard::GameBoard(solution);
        cout>>"Please make a guess or enter 'Q' to quit: ";
        string guess;
        getline(cin, guess);

        if(guess.size() == 1)
            menuSelection(guess); // <-- and here
        else
            currentGame.checkGuess(guess);
    }
}
```

Would placing each menuSelection or printMenu call in a try catch be the most effective way to deal with this?

Comment: why not simply call `exit(0)` ?

Comment: exit(0) I believe will not unwind the stack and will only call destructors for the variables currently in scope. Thus leaving every other object unaccounted for.  This may be incorrect as i said i am fairly new to C++ however that is my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is either exit(0) (which I do NOT recommend, since it does not unwind the stack) or throwing an exception which is caught at the top-level of the program.

EDIT: Code

```
void menuSelection(string input){
    if(input == 'Q')
        throw std::runtime_error; // Maybe use another exception class
```

Main function would become

```
int main(){
    printMainMenu(); // <-- menuSelection called here

    try {
        while(cin >> solution){
            GameBoard currentGame = GameBoard::GameBoard(solution);
            cout>>"Please make a guess or enter 'Q' to quit: ";
            string guess;
            getline(cin, guess);

            if(guess.size() == 1)
                menuSelection(guess); // <-- and here
            else
                currentGame.checkGuess(guess);
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        // Quit
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this was to have a class that manages the whole game. This would have a `bool` sigalling if it should exit. All those functions would become members of this class.

```
class GameLogic {
  bool should_quit = false;

  void mainLoop() {
    while (!should_quit) {
       // call whatever you need
    }
  }
  void someDeepNestedCalledFunction() {
    if (whatever_reason) {
       should_quit = true;    
       return;
    }
  }
};
```